# DFPlayer Module Sleep mode working for anyone?

Tags: microcontroller, mp3, dfplayer

I'm trying to put a DFPlayer module into sleep mode. 
The command seems to be: **7E FF 06 0A 00 00 00 FE F1 EF**. The normal power consumption my supply is showing (when the module is idle) is about 15mA, after sending the sleep command I read exactly the same. Sending the command another time will get an error (0x40).

Anyone observed similar behavior?

Comment: note:  the datasheet specifies a standby current of 20mA.

Comment: I actually noticed that, but assumed that is incorrect as the current I see when power up the device is less. Even if my power supply is wrong by 25% I would have expected to see a lower current after putting the device is sleep mode?

Comment: the player uses the YX5300-24SS chip. .... found this data sheet that specifies standby current of < 200μA .... maybe the chip goes to sleep, but the SD card does not (not sure about SD cards)?? .... https://xp-dev.com/trac/arduino_antonio/export/280/arduino_antonio/trunk/EnterpriseBase/Serial%20MP3%20Player/About%20the%20Chip%20-%20YX5300/YX5300-24SS%20Datasheet%20V1.0.pdf

Comment: The module also has the 8002 audio amplifier IC, datasheet says between 7.5 to 10mA current consumption. Shutdown current 2uA. Not sure the shutdown pin is connected.

Comment: 8002 audio amplifier IC .... pull pin #1 high to enter shutdown state .... maybe you can trace the connection